# JBoss - ExportException: Port already in use: 1098

Tags: windows, networking, jboss, tcp

I'm getting the following error when I try to start JBoss

```
10:10:43,298 INFO  [WebService] Using RMI server codebase: http://127.0.0.1:8083/
10:10:43,938 ERROR [AbstractKernelController] Error installing to Start: name=jboss:service=Naming state=Create mode=Manual requiredState=Installed
java.rmi.server.ExportException: Port already in use: 1098; nested exception is: 
    java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.listen(TCPTransport.java:249)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.exportObject(TCPTransport.java:184)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.exportObject(TCPEndpoint.java:382)
    at sun.rmi.transport.LiveRef.exportObject(LiveRef.java:116)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.exportObject(UnicastServerRef.java:180)
    at java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(UnicastRemoteObject.java:293)
    at java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(UnicastRemoteObject.java:256)
```

However When I try to see what ports are being listened to. I don't see that port!

```
H:\>netstat -a -n -o

Active Connections

  Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State           PID
  TCP    0.0.0.0:135            0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       824
  TCP    0.0.0.0:445            0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       4
  TCP    0.0.0.0:1521           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       2036
  TCP    0.0.0.0:3389           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       752
  TCP    0.0.0.0:7717           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       2944
  TCP    0.0.0.0:8081           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       1564
  TCP    0.0.0.0:31038          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       1436
  TCP    127.0.0.1:1038         0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       2036
  TCP    127.0.0.1:1052         0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       2620
  TCP    127.0.0.1:5998         127.0.0.1:5999         ESTABLISHED     4036
  TCP    127.0.0.1:5999         127.0.0.1:5998         ESTABLISHED     4036
  TCP    127.0.0.1:6000         127.0.0.1:6001         ESTABLISHED     4036
  TCP    127.0.0.1:6001         127.0.0.1:6000         ESTABLISHED     4036
  TCP    142.174.27.74:139      0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       4
  TCP    142.174.27.74:13148    142.174.12.84:445      ESTABLISHED     4
  TCP    142.174.27.74:13253    142.174.134.33:8080    ESTABLISHED     4036
  TCP    142.174.27.74:13255    142.174.134.33:8080    ESTABLISHED     4036
  TCP    142.174.27.74:13258    142.174.134.33:8080    ESTABLISHED     4036
  TCP    142.174.27.74:13259    142.174.134.33:8080    ESTABLISHED     4036
  TCP    142.174.27.74:13260    142.174.134.33:8080    ESTABLISHED     4036
  TCP    142.174.27.74:13261    142.174.134.33:8080    ESTABLISHED     4036
  TCP    142.174.27.74:13262    142.174.134.33:8080    ESTABLISHED     4036
  TCP    142.174.27.74:13263    142.174.134.33:8080    ESTABLISHED     4036
  UDP    0.0.0.0:445            *:*                                    4
  UDP    0.0.0.0:8081           *:*                                    1564
  UDP    0.0.0.0:8082           *:*                                    1564
  UDP    0.0.0.0:19508          *:*                                    1244
  UDP    127.0.0.1:123          *:*                                    948
  UDP    127.0.0.1:1025         *:*                                    580
  UDP    127.0.0.1:1046         *:*                                    524
  UDP    127.0.0.1:1056         *:*                                    784
  UDP    127.0.0.1:1213         *:*                                    2888
  UDP    127.0.0.1:1257         *:*                                    2404
  UDP    127.0.0.1:2172         *:*                                    3736
  UDP    127.0.0.1:2310         *:*                                    2188
  UDP    142.174.27.74:123      *:*                                    948
  UDP    142.174.27.74:137      *:*                                    4
  UDP    142.174.27.74:138      *:*                                    4

H:\>
```

any ideas?

Thanks,

Tam

Comment: Any firewall (ISA) client running? Or some ISS service. Did you also try with TCPView

Comment: Was the last JBoss shutdown clean? Which windows are you using? Windows before 2008 could sometimes reserve ports between 1025-5000 for his own uses http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929851/en-us

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try TCPView ([TCPView v3.05](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897437.aspx)). I get this "port already in use" quite a lot, and TCPView <strike>always</strike> usually catches the culprit.

Comment: Useful, but also see this quicker solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6438810/396747

Answer (score 4):

Go to jboss-service.xml under conf folder and change the port for RMI from 1098 to 8099

```
8099
```

Restart the server .

Comment: +1 for a great solution - not everyone can edit their registry settings

Answer (score 2):

We ran into this problem some time ago as well, not just with JBoss, but also MySQL.
I wrote about it in more detail here:

[Windows TCP Port Conflicts above 1024](http://www.jroller.com/dschneller/entry/windows_tcp_port_conflicts_above)

What it comes down to is that Windows uses the port range between 1000 and 5000 for so called "ephemeral" ports. This means that it assigns ports from this range for processes that request a random port.

On Windows 2000/2003 Server installations as well as on Windows XP Pro you can reserve port ranges (even if they only cover a single port) for your applications. Effectively they are not reserved for anything specific, but just excluded from the dynamic allocation. To do so, create or edit the following registry value (type `REG_MULTI_SZ/Multi-String Value`):

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\ReservedPorts
```

In this value specify port ranges in the format xxxx-yyyy with xxxx and yyyy being the lowest and highest port of the range to be reserved. To reserve a single port, just use the same values for both (e. g. 1099).

Comment: any ideas how to achieve the same result in Windows7?

Answer (score 2):

I guess that port is still in use. You can find that using:

```
netstat -ao
```

and

```
netstat -b
```

If you can't use that port, find another port and change it in the following XML file:

```
conf/bindings-beans/META-INF/bindings-jboss-beans.xml
```

The JBoss 5 has a new ServiceBindingManager which uses bean injection to assign ports at runtime. Changing the port here may do the trick for you.
You can also use a different ports configuration and override the ports by a factor.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the ports mentioned in the file referenced by Sam, and the registry key referenced by Daniel Schneller, the following should do the trick for JBoss EAP 5:

1090-1090 1098-1102 1161-1162 3528-3528 4444-4448 4457-4457 4712-4714 5445-5446 8080-8083 8443-8443

Translated in a .reg file:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters]
"ReservedPorts"=hex(7):31,00,30,00,39,00,30,00,2d,00,31,00,30,00,39,00,30,00,\
  20,00,31,00,30,00,39,00,38,00,2d,00,31,00,31,00,30,00,32,00,20,00,31,00,31,\
  00,36,00,31,00,2d,00,31,00,31,00,36,00,32,00,20,00,33,00,35,00,32,00,38,00,\
  2d,00,33,00,35,00,32,00,38,00,20,00,34,00,34,00,34,00,34,00,2d,00,34,00,34,\
  00,34,00,38,00,20,00,34,00,34,00,35,00,37,00,2d,00,34,00,34,00,35,00,37,00,\
  20,00,34,00,37,00,31,00,32,00,2d,00,34,00,37,00,31,00,34,00,20,00,35,00,34,\
  00,34,00,35,00,2d,00,35,00,34,00,34,00,36,00,20,00,38,00,30,00,38,00,30,00,\
  2d,00,38,00,30,00,38,00,33,00,20,00,38,00,34,00,34,00,33,00,2d,00,38,00,34,\
  00,34,00,33,00,00,00,00,00
```

Comment: or, and I just realised this, you could probably just emulate the Windows Vista+ behaviour with the single range "1024-49151"...

Answer (score 2):

The root cause is that JBOSS was not peoperly shut down.
If you are using Windows,
go to task manager and kill the JBOSS processes.

Answer (score 2):

Reserve the port 1098-1099 in registry.
Restart the oracle service if running, then start the JBOss.

Answer (score 1):

This error is also thrown by Jboss if your default IP address changes due to some problem
means
   121.*.*.89  to 121.*.*.90     Just  check it and replace it with a newer IP address. It will work.